# rtl direction doesn't work by using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

the file bootstrap.min.css doesn't let me use rtl in my page. the page is still ltr. is there any way to change it?-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>digikala</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body dir="rtl">
      <div class="container-fluid header">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">q</div>
            <div class="col">q</div>
            <div class="col">q</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">q</div>
             <div class="col">q</div>
              <h1>




  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap not support RTL and you can use RTL Bootstrap from this sites:

```
http://bootstrapper.ir
https://bootstrap.rtlcss.com
https://github.com/MahdiMajidzadeh/bootstrap-v4-rtl
https://github.com/PerseusTheGreat/bootstrap-4-rtl
```

Comment: when I try to npm install this to my project I get a lot of warnings about security. Is it worth the risk?